# Why is the p-value written with a supremum?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, mathematical-statistics, p-value

I noticed that there is a definition of the pvalue in my textbook is defined says the following:

[image]

I have no idea why it is written with a supremum. I've spent hours pondering this, does anyone have enough of a background to help me with this? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often the null hypothesis is actually a composite hypothesis such as $H_0: \theta \le \theta_0$, so we could calculate the probability of the test statistic at $\theta_0$, but also at $\theta_0 - 1$ or $\theta_0 - 0.01$ or an infinite number of other values.  So we choose the largest among all the possible values as the p-value.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking why do we choose the largest value?

Comment: @user123276, If I claimed that I was taller than everyone in your family and you wanted to test that claim it would be enough to compare my height to that of the tallest member of your family.  We could compare my height to everyone in you family, but it would not change the conclusion relative to only comparing to the tallest.  On the other hand, if I can show that I am taller than some members of your family (but don't compare to the tallest), that does not really confirm my claim.  Same with the p-value, the test is based on all possible being less than alpha, so we just compare the largest